# Telegram API and Wrappers: Can you check if a user exists just from username?

Tags: api, telegram

What the title says.
Is is possible to check if a user exists on telegram.org just knowing their username? I am trying to do this through API as opposed to a slow selenium/etc.
Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: I recommend using this library:

https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramApi

Comment: there is an api called account.checkUsername . use this for checking availibility state of a username.

Comment: Bots can't do that

Answer (score 1):

there is an api called account.checkUsername . use this for checking availibility state of a username. – tashakori

ended up using telethon for this, thank you all